# How can i change the order of p-tabPanel dynamically

Tags: angular, primeng, tabview

I'm using Primeng `tabView`, and i'm looking for a way to change the order of a `tabPanel` dynamically, for example i put a dropdown with two options ['One', 'Two'], and if i select option One the order of `tabPabels` will be  Godfather I, Godfather II, if i select option Two the order will be
Godfather II, Godfather I

**HTML :**

```
Condition :
<p-dropdown [options]="choices" [(ngModel)]="choice"
     placeholder="Sélectionner" optionLabel="name" >
</p-dropdown>



<p-tabView>
    <p-tabPanel header="Godfather I" leftIcon="pi pi-calendar">
        
    </p-tabPanel>

    <p-tabPanel header="Godfather II" leftIcon="pi pi-inbox">
        
    </p-tabPanel>

</p-tabView>
```

**TS :**

```
choices : String[] = ['One', 'Two'];
choice : String;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen to dropdown changes

**html**

```
<p-dropdown [options]="choices" [(ngModel)]="choice" placeholder="Sélectionner" 
     (onChange)="sortTabs($event.value)">
</p-dropdown>
```

Then make use of `ngFor` directive:

**html**

```
<p-tabView>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of tabs">
        <p-tabPanel *ngIf="item === 'one'" header="Godfather I" leftIcon="pi pi-calendar">
            content 1
        </p-tabPanel>
        <p-tabPanel *ngIf="item === 'two'" header="Godfather II" leftIcon="pi pi-inbox">
            content 2
        </p-tabPanel>
    </ng-container>
</p-tabView>
```

And, finally, sort tabPanel order:

**ts**

```
choices: any[] = [
  {
    label: "One",
    value: "one"
  },
  { 
    label: "Two",
    value: "two"
  }
];

choice: String = 'one';

tabs = ['one', 'two'];

sortTabs(value) {
  if (value === 'one') {
    this.tabs.sort();
  } else {
    this.tabs.reverse();
  }
}
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dropdown-demo-vdvsth?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**